# Заполнение компонентов при вызове фрагмента

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, activity

Суть такая, моё приложение состоит из множества фрагментов, и активити. Я делал так из-за не опытности в разработке android приложений, просто по другому не умел, не судите строго. В основном эти фрагменты имеют одинаковые разметки, можно ли так сделать, чтобы, допустим, было 2-3 главных фрагментов с компонентами `listview`, и один фрагмент чтобы при его очередном вызове, заполнялись его `listview` и `textview`. То есть вот так: вызываем его при клике на первый элемент списка главного фрагмента -  его `listview` и `textview` заполняются одними данными, при нажатии на второй уже другими и так далее. Как так можно реализовать. Если я что-то не так понимаю поправьте меня пожалуйста.

```
ListView listView;
    int [] imgs = {R.drawable.__1,R.drawable.__1b,R.drawable.__2,R.drawable.__3,R.drawable.__3a,R.drawable.__5,
            R.drawable.__5a,R.drawable.__6,R.drawable.__7,R.drawable.__8,R.drawable.__9,R.drawable.__10,R.drawable.__11,
            R.drawable.__12,R.drawable.__14,R.drawable.__15,R.drawable.__16_,R.drawable.__18,R.drawable.__19,R.drawable.__20,
            R.drawable.__23,R.drawable.__24};

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_route, container, false);
        getActivity().setTitle(R.string.fr1);
        listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listView);
        List<String> arr = getTextFromRaw();
        //заполнение списка данными
        ArrayList<Map<String, Object>> date = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>(arr.size());
        Map <String, Object> map;
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++){
            map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            map.put("name",arr.get(i));
            map.put("imgs",imgs[i]);
            date.add(map);
        }
        String [] from = {"name","imgs"};
        int [] to = {R.id.n1,R.id.image};
         // создааем адаптер и настраиваем список
        SimpleAdapter ad = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(),date,R.layout.test,from,to);

        listView.setAdapter(ad);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int p, long id) {
                switch(p) {
                    case 0:
                        startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), dir1.class));
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), dir1b.class));
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), dir2.class));
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), dir3.class));
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), dir3a.class));
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), dir5.class));
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), dir5a.class));
                        break;
                    case 7:
                        startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), dir6.class));
                        break;
                    case 8:
                        startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), dir7.class));
                        break;
                    case 9:
                        startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), dir8.class));
                        break;
                    case 10:
                        startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), dir9.class));
                        break;
                    case 11:
                        startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), dir10.class));
                        break;
                    case 12:
                        startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), dir11.class));
                        break;
                    case 13:
                        startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), dir12.class));
                        break;
                    case 14:
                        startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), dir14.class));
                        break;
                    case 15:
                        startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), dir15.class));
                        break;
                    case 16:
                        startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), dir16a.class));
                        break;
                    case 17:
                        startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), dir18.class));
                        break;
                    case 18:
                        startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), dir19.class));
                        break;
                    case 19:
                        startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), dir20.class));
                        break;
                    case 20:
                        startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), dir23.class));
                        break;
                    case 21:
                        startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), dir24.class));
                        break;
                }

            }
        });
        return rootView;
    }
```

Вот это код якобы главного фрагмента, как видите я вызываю activity их аж 22 штуки, то есть мне приходилось каждый раз создавать новую. Я спрашиваю так можно ли можно ли вызывать одну каждый раз одну и туже активити но передавать разметке с её компонентами что я заполняю каждый раз по разному? просто я задрался создавать кучу активити может есть пример реализации такого?

Comment: Не понятно то, что вы хотите спросить. Обьясните по подробнее или приведите пример.

Comment: Не только можно, но и необходимо. Пример - исходники  любого приложения android.  Что должны отображать все эти активити dir* и в чем между ними различие? Для начала можете изучить шаблон Master Detail Flow, который  предлагается при создании проекта в Android Studio/

Comment: @pavlofff дир отображают список listview

Comment: @pavlofff различие кроме как содержания листвию никакого

Comment: @pavlofff я уже как бы научился использовать Drawar navigation activity я думаю что master detal flow мне не очень подходит, иерархия такая первый фрагмент главный в нем список -> потом dir-activity разметка одна и та же меняется только содержимое списка-> ещё одна активити со списком тоже такой же разметки как и dir -> конечное активити немного с другим содержимым чем все остальные.

Comment: шаблон master detail flow демонстрирует как правильно создать список, при клике на элементы которого открывается одна и та же активити с деталями по именно этому элементу - это же то, о чем вы спрашиваете?. Никто вас не заставляет использовать этот шаблон, посмотрите, как там все устроено и делайте на его основе как вам надо.

Comment: @pavlofff все бы хорошо только не нашел уроков на русском языке по этому никаких

Comment: @pavlofff я так понял он для планшетов или как?

Answer (score 1):

Основной принцип организации использования одной активити (фрагмента) для отображения различного контента на одинаковой разметке такой, что создается структура данных (например, база данных), промаркированная каким-либо ключом, например, каждый набор данных, для отображения по одному элементу списка, маркируется номером позиции в этом списке или в случае с БД - уникальным ID.

При нажатии на пункт списка вызывается одна и та же активити, в которую через `Intent` передается ключ-идентификатор данных, в нашем случае номер позиции в списке (или ID записи для БД).

Вызванная активити принимает этот ключ и по нему делает выборку данных из той структуры, что была создана в первом пункте и заполняет полученными данными контент виджетов.

Примеров такого шаблона огромное множество, фактически почти любой пример со списком и подробностями по пункту при клике на элемент.